# SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: ruby, ssl, certificate, openssl, imap

I have a ruby client that connects to an exchange server using IMAP & SSL. I use the Ruby Net::IMAP library (which uses openssl under the covers) to connect. Its been working fine for months. The exchange server admin installed new cert from godaddy and now I get this error:

```
 SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

Does anyone know what this error means? (I tried googling)

I suspect there is an issue with the new cert causing this, but I dont know how to troubleshoot it.

Also I know you can disable certificate verification when using NET:HTTP by doing:

```
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if http.use_ssl?
```

but I cant figure out how to do this using NET:IMAP. I want to disable this to see if this is the problem.

As for code im using:
Im using this(or very close to this) http://github.com/look/fetcher/blob/master/lib/fetcher/imap.rb

I tried changing to :
     @connection = Net::IMAP.new(@server, @port, @ssl, nil, false)

Here is the stacktrace

```
 checking emails on: Tue Aug 17 20:48:01 +0000 2010
 rake aborted!
 SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:904:in `connect'
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:904:in `initialize' 
 /u/apps/aras/releases/20100728212439/vendor/plugins/fetcher/lib/fetcher/imap.rb:34:in `new'
 /u/apps/aras/releases/20100728212439/vendor/plugins/fetcher/lib/fetcher/imap.rb:34:in `establish_connection'
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/system_timer-1.0/lib/system_timer.rb:28:in `timeout_after'
 /u/apps/aras/releases/20100728212439/vendor/plugins/fetcher/lib/fetcher/imap.rb:33:in `establish_connection'
 /u/apps/aras/releases/20100728212439/vendor/plugins/fetcher/lib/fetcher/base.rb:31:in `fetch'
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the value of timeout_call (probably not the issue)?  Also, I assume you tested connecting to the IMAP server with another IMAP client & verified it worked, correct?

Comment: Tried increasing timeout, but it fails very quickly. Haven tried another client, but this did work before they made the change on the server.

Comment: I'd double check with another client and/or inspect the certificate to ensure there is nothing horribly wrong with it (like the hostname on the cert doesn't match the hostname you are connecting to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out the root cause on this one was ms exchange was misconfigured. I would love to have learned more about ssl errors and how to troublshoot them, but I just didnt get much info on this.

I did try to just troublshoot this using open ssl, fyi, you can do:
OpenSSL> s_client -connect myserver:993

When it was broken, I received this error:
CONNECTED(00000003)
26831:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
failure:s23_lib.c:188:

Once we fixed I got a cert and handshake message etc.

Here is what my exchange admin said he did: "I just went to the IMAP protocol and went to the access tab.  Then the certificates button.  From there I chose to replace the cert and chose the new cert."

Answer (score 3):

I received this error trying to connect to dynamoDB with rails 3 using the default setup.
Solution was to add

```
config.port = 443
```

to the

> dynamo_db.rb

initializer

As of this writing this fix is in an unmerged branch of the gem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html#M000754), you can set the SSL verification to none when instantiating Net:IMAP

```
foo = Net::IMAP.new(host, port, true, nil, false)
```

You can also point to a local copy of the CA cert with the `certs` option.

note: I haven't tried this myself...

Comment: Thanks, tried, this, still same error, thanks, I am not sure if this is the same thing or not.