# Why do I get OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError when installing Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, openssl

When I run `'sudo gem install rails'`, this error occurs:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
```

BTW, I'm running Ruby version 1.9.3p0, Gem version 2.0.3, and OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Any advice?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506754/ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv2-v3-read-server-hello-a, also can try the http source (vs https default). https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/515

Answer (score 23):

Please try the following commands

**Root causes**

1) outdate open SSL

```
$ rvm -v
$ rvm get head
```

2) outdate bundle

```
$ gem install bundle
```

hope it will solve

Comment: +1 updating openssl using pacman in Arch linux solved this issue

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$ gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was about installing rails, I also get the exact same error. As Aye Mon Chit mention earlier, this error is possibly caused by an outdated open SSL. Here's my solution: update your openssl
In my Wheezy, I simply run:

```
apt-get install openssl
```

And that's all. Hope this help somebody out there.