# Unable to install gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am unable to install gems, what changes do I need to do in my settings of browser to get downloaded? I am using **Windows 7**

```
C:\Users\MAX JOHN>gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (https://ruby
gems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

---

```
C:\Users\MAX JOHN>gem install mysql
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (https://ruby
gems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Maybe you got some proxy issues.

Comment: Proxy is fine with me.I think the problem with the SSL CERTIFICATE.HOW TO DISABLE IT?P.S:I'm beginner to rails and freshly installing this to my laptop.

Comment: Try with `gem install rails --no-http-proxy` or `gem install rails --source 'http://rubygems.org'` or other solution on this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506754/1297435)

Comment: When I ran Ruby on Windows I encountered problems when the path to my project contained a space like yours has in "MAX JOHN". I don't think it's relevant to this particular problem, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

setting the source to http instead of https is not recommended as it creates security issues.
Try pinging https://rubygems.org, this will tell you if the problem is with your connection issues or not.

Assuming you're using Rails 3, have a look at this post on how to set up WEBrick to use SSL:

http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of Ruby installed?  I accidentally upgraded without removing a prior installation, and removing that fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem, and solved it by:

1. Downloading the gem via web browser from https://rubygems.org/
2. Install it locally by cd ing into the dir where the gem was downloaded and ran:
   gem install --local .gem